# How to write unit test case for a call being called to another class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test case for one of my functions in a class. However I am not able to figure out how I should mimic the result of a call to another class.

```
public class ScriptCheckExecutor implements CheckEx {
public int runCheck(Check check) {
..
try {
  exitValue = new VSPProcessHandler(check.getId(), pb.start()).waitFor(timeout.get());
            InstanceStatus s;
switch (exitValue) {
            case 0:
                s = InstanceStatus.toEnum("UP");
                check.addStatus(StatusType.HEALTHY);
                break;
            case 1:
                check.addStatus(StatusType.WARN);
                break;
}
ApplicationInfoManager aim = ApplicationInfoManager.getInstance();
            aim.setInstanceStatus(s);
}
catch(Exception e) {
....
}
}
```

In my unit test case file, how should I proceed with calls to InstanceStatus.toEnum, since I cannot test if the value has actually been updated from a test file?

Comment: You seem to be assuming we know a lot more about your code than we actually do.

Comment: using Mock if you don't want to depend on InstanceStatus